# Where I could learn about router command line?

Tags: router, wireless, lan

I'm using Huawei

Device type: HG8245A

Description: EchoLife HG8245A GPON Terminal (CLASS B+/PRODUCT ID:21500821523GE3017523)

I'm trying to learn telnet on Windows and then I'm curious about the command line on my router

When I typed help/?

```
WAP>?
amp clear
amp debug lswtable all
amp display efc
amp display l2act
amp display l2mac
amp display sfc
amp display userflow
amp show
backup cfg
clear poncnt dnstatistic
clear poncnt gemport upstatistic
clear poncnt upstatistic
clear port statistics
debug bbsp
debug ddns
debug ifm
debug qoscfg
display access mode
display apmChipStatus
display apmpolicy
display batteryStatus
display boardItem
display boot
display cwmp debug
display deviceInfo
display dhcp_em result
display epon ont info
display eponkey
display equip test mode
display equipId
display equiptest status
display ethoam ma info
display ethoam md info
display ethoam mep info
display ethoam mep perf
display flow
display inner version
display lanmac
display machineItem
display msg-queue
display ont config-restore info
display onu info
display optic
display optmode
display poncnt dnstatistic
display poncnt gemport upstatistic
display poncnt upstatistic
display portstatistics
display pppoe_em result
display productId
display productmac
display sn
display swm bootstate
display swm state
display sysinfo
display syslog
display telnet access
display timeout
display timer
display usb devList
display userinfo
display vendorId
display version
display wanmac
display wlanmac
equip test mode off
get battery alarm status
get countbosa
get mac agingtime
get ont oamfrequency
get opm switch
get optic txmode
get poncnt upgemport
get port config
get port isolate
get port mac numlimit
get port statistics
get port vlan
get rogue status
get testself
get vlan auth
get wlan advance
get wlan associated
get wlan basic
get wlan enable
get wlan psk
get wlan stats
get wlan wep key
get wlan wps
history
igmp clear statistics
igmp get debug switch
igmp get flow info
igmp get global cfg
igmp get iptv
igmp get multilmac
igmp get port multicast config
igmp get statistics
igmp set debug switch
igmp set iptv
load pack
logout
mtest
napt cli
qoscfg get
quit
reset
route get default
save data
save log
set bosa
set cwmp debug
set ethportmirror
set oamdebug
set ringchk
set timeout
set userpasswd
set voicedebug
set voicedsploop
set voicelinetest
set voiceportloop
set voicesignalingprint
set wlan enable
shell
sntp get
su
system rollback
vspa debug
vspa display confrence info
vspa display dsp running info
vspa display dsp state
vspa display mg if state
vspa display mg info
vspa display online user info
vspa display port status
vspa display signal scene info
vspa display signal scene list
vspa display user call state
vspa display user status
vspa mgc switch
vspa remote capture server set
vspa remote capture set
vspa reset
vspa set ptcflag
vspa shutdown mg
vspa voiptest
```

so, where I could learn about those command lines to setting my router?

and I found this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

could I say that all of router command lines are hayes command?

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Hayes commands only apply to dial-up modems that are far less common nowadays than 20 years ago.

Each manufacturer has is own software embedded in its products and so its own command line.

Some choose to implement command line the behave like other well known manufacturers (like Cisco) so you may find very similar command lines on equipment from different vendors, but this is less common on home office grade equipment.

You  have to rely mainly on the vendor documentation - which is often poor- and the embedded help.